# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `element` of type `function` supplied to `Group`, expected `object`

Tags: reactjs

I imported component from src/components folder of Search, Dropdown and Group

The Group component contains search and dropdown component and from that I created a Product page to show them.

This is my code for that
`src/pages/product.`

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Header from "../../components/Header/index"
import Group from "../../components/Group/index"
import Dropdown from "../../components/Dropdown/index"
import Search from "../../components/Search/index"
import ProductItem from "../../components/ProductItem/index"
import "../Product/index.css";

const Product = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Header />
      <Row>
        <Group
          title="Product group"
          element={<Dropdown items={["Milk Tea", "Juice"]} />}
        />
        <Group
          title="Sort by price"
          element={<Dropdown items={["Low to hight", "Hight to low"]} />}
        />
        <Group
          title="Search"
          element={Search}
        />
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Product;
```

And here is in `src/component/Group`

```
import React from "react";
import { Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "../Group/index.css";
import "../../common/index.css";

const Group = ({ title, element }) => {
  return (
    <Col bsPrefix="group">
      <h4 className="title group-title">{title}</h4>
      <Row className="group-element">{element}</Row>
    </Col>
  );
};

Group.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  element: PropTypes.object,
};

Group.defaultProps = {
  title: "",
  element: [],
};

export default Group;
```

I don't understand why to have this warning, I don't know where I wrong

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `element` of type `function` supplied to `Group`, expected `object`.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing a react element as the element prop, you should accept it as PropTypes.func in your Group component. **func** covers types for functional as well as react components passed as props. Please try this, it should work.

```
Group.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  element: PropTypes.func,
};

Group.defaultProps = {
  title: "",
  element: ()=>{},
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting object. And passing defaultProps array. Either do:

```
Group.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  element: PropTypes.object,
};

Group.defaultProps = {
  title: "",
  element: {},
};
```

or

```
Group.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  element: PropTypes.array,
};

Group.defaultProps = {
  title: "",
  element: [],
};
```